# get column index from prop in after change function of handsontable

Tags: javascript, parameters, handsontable

there is a problem getting the column index in after change function of Handsontable, in old versions it was much clear than now, in this function parameter changes gives out:
2D array containing information about each of the edited cells [[row, prop, oldVal, newVal], ...] but where is the COLUMN!?

thank you all for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `propToCol(prop)` to get column index ;)

Comment: Yes! this is the right answer )) the problem was because im using the model for handsontable, thus define columns property by function... now I understand what u did :) thank you!